# Delete From Database

Tags: magento-1.9

**phtml**

```
<form id="Upload" action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('followup/index/follow') ?>" method="post"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>"/>
    <p><input id="customer_name" type="hidden" name="customer_name" value="<?php echo $customer->getName(); ?>"></p>
    <p><input id="customer_email" type="hidden" name="customer_email" value="<?php echo $customer->getEmail(); ?>"></p>
    <p><input id="seller_id" type="hidden" name="seller_id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"></p>
    <p><input id="seller_email" type="hidden" name="seller_email" value="<?php echo $customerData->getEmail(); ?>"></p>
    <p><input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Follow me!"></p>
</form>
```

**controller**

```
public function followAction(){
    $cus_name = ''.$this->getRequest()->getPost('customer_name');
    $cus_email = ''.$this->getRequest()->getPost('customer_email');
    $seller_id = ''.$this->getRequest()->getPost('seller_id');
    $seller_email = ''.$this->getRequest()->getPost('seller_email');

    $collection = Mage::getModel('followup/followup');
    $collection ->setData('customer_name',$cus_name);
    $collection ->setData('customer_email',$cus_email);
    $collection ->setData('seller_id',$seller_id);
    $collection ->setData('seller_email',$seller_email);
    $collection->save();
}
```

It's insert database successfully but I want to delete if already exist ? How to write controller on that?

Comment: Yes @QaisarSatti

Comment: if Seller id & Seller email & Customer Email are same then only it delete

Comment: if no data is found then add new that your requirement.?

Comment: Yes @QaisarSatti you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this:

```
public function followAction() {

    $cus_name = $this->getRequest()->getPost('customer_name');
    $cus_email = $this->getRequest()->getPost('customer_email');
    $seller_id = $this->getRequest()->getPost('seller_id');
    $seller_email = $this->getRequest()->getPost('seller_email');

    $checkcollection = Mage::getModel('followup/followup')->getCollection();
    $checkcollection->addFieldToFilter('customer_email',$cus_email);
    $checkcollection->addFieldToFilter('seller_id',$seller_id);
    $checkcollection->addFieldToFilter('seller_email',$seller_email);

    if (count($checkcollection)) {

        foreach ($checkcollection as $kcollection) {
            Mage::getModel('followup/followup')->load($kcollection->getFollowupId())->delete();
        }
    } 

    // Save new data anyway
    $collection = Mage::getModel('followup/followup');
    $collection ->setData('customer_name',$cus_name);
    $collection ->setData('customer_email',$cus_email);
    $collection ->setData('seller_id',$seller_id);
    $collection ->setData('seller_email',$seller_email);

    $collection->save();
}
```

for from button

```
  <form id="Upload" action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('followup/index/follow') ?>" method="post"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>"/>
    <p><input id="customer_name" type="hidden" name="customer_name" value="<?php echo $customer->getName(); ?>"></p>
    <p><input id="customer_email" type="hidden" name="customer_email" value="<?php echo $customer->getEmail(); ?>"></p>
    <p><input id="seller_id" type="hidden" name="seller_id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"></p>
    <p><input id="seller_email" type="hidden" name="seller_email" value="<?php echo $customerData->getEmail(); ?>"></p>
    <p><input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Follow me!"></p>
</form>
```

use that code

```
<?php 
$checkcollection = Mage::getModel('followup/followup')->getCollection();
    $checkcollection->addFieldToFilter('customer_email',$customer->getEmail());
    $checkcollection->addFieldToFilter('seller_id',$id);
    $checkcollection->addFieldToFilter('seller_email',$customerData->getEmail());

    if (count($checkcollection)) {
        //for exiting record add you button code here
    } else { //for not exiting record add you button code here  
    } ?>
```

Comment: Can you please explain this part $ids=$checkcollection->getAllIds();
        foreach($ids as $id){
        Mage::getModel('followup/followup')->load($id)->delete();

Comment: this will return   current ids of collection because for deleting the record  we need the ids so i used this logic..

Comment: Ya it's working but if already available in DB i need a different button if not there i need a different button how to achive this

Comment: where you want to show that button can you add that code?

Comment: In frontend i already added that code check my question

Comment: added the answer follow that

Comment: Hi sorry for late reply after adding this page shows Blank

Comment: i think you paste the same code without any change. updated code check now

Comment: Delete Not Working Properly if same record has two time then only it delete other wise it just reload the page

Comment: `echo count($checkcollection);` check number of record. it is showing correct or not

Comment: it shows 1 how to delete that also

Comment: `print_r($ids);` what is output of this?

Comment: Where i need to add phtml or controller

Comment: where you are deleting the record

Comment: In frontend i added but no output

Comment: add it in controller after `$ids = $checkcollection->getAllIds();`

Comment: it's already there

Comment: updated code check it it is working

Comment: No Luck Still same

Comment: `print_r($checkcollection);` and paste the output here

Comment: it printed 1000's of line which one you want

Comment: `print_r($checkcollection->getData());` try that and check the output

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [followup_id] => 26 [customer_name] => Test test [customer_email] => customer.@gmail.com [seller_id] => 1016 [seller_email] => sellerr@gmail.com ) )

Comment: updated code try that...

Comment: No luck still reload the page only not delete

Comment: echo `$kcollection->getFollowupId();` this will give you correct it?

Comment: Sorry i am not getting

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38620/discussion-on-answer-by-qaisar-satti-delete-from-database).

Answer (score 0):

Controller code as below:

```
public function followAction(){
        $cus_name = ''.$this->getRequest()->getPost('customer_name');
        $cus_email = ''.$this->getRequest()->getPost('customer_email');
        $seller_id = ''.$this->getRequest()->getPost('seller_id');
        $seller_email = ''.$this->getRequest()->getPost('seller_email');


        $model = Mage::getModel('followup/followup');
        $collection = $model->getCollection();

        //you don't need to filter multiple field you can only filter your collection using primary key 

        $collection ->addFieldToFilter('customer_name',$cus_name);
        $collection ->addFieldToFilter('customer_email',$cus_email);
        $collection ->addFieldToFilter('seller_id',$seller_id);
        $collection ->addFieldToFilter('seller_email',$seller_email);

        if(count($collection)){
           foreach($collection as $child){
                $model->load($child->getId())->delete();
           }else{
                $model->load(null);
                $model->setData('customer_name',$cus_name);
                $model->setData('customer_email',$cus_email);
                $model->setData('seller_id',$seller_id);
                $model->setData('seller_email',$seller_email);
                $model->save();
           }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you will use this code

```
if (count($checkcollection)) {
    $ids = $checkcollection->getAllIds();
    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        Mage::getModel('followup/followup')->load($id)->delete();
    }
} else {

    $collection = Mage::getModel('followup/followup');
    $collection ->setData('customer_name',$cus_name);
    $collection ->setData('customer_email',$cus_email);
    $collection ->setData('seller_id',$seller_id);
    $collection ->setData('seller_email',$seller_email);

    $collection->save();
}
```

Then records will be deleted, but new record will not be created. 
If you need just to delete before saving new record - there should be no ELSE case. Like this:

```
if (count($checkcollection)) {
    $ids = $checkcollection->getAllIds();
    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        Mage::getModel('followup/followup')->load($id)->delete();
    }
}

$collection = Mage::getModel('followup/followup');
$collection ->setData('customer_name',$cus_name);
$collection ->setData('customer_email',$cus_email);
$collection ->setData('seller_id',$seller_id);
$collection ->setData('seller_email',$seller_email);
$collection->save();
```

OR - much better - just to "do nothing" if record exists.

```
  if (!count($checkcollection)) {
        Mage::getModel('followup/followup')->setData(
                             array(
                                'customer_name' => $cus_name,
                                'customer_email' => $cus_email,
                                'seller_id' => $seller_id,
                                'seller_email' => $seller_email
                             )
                       )->save();
    }
```